# Is the NSDate on every iOS device synchronized?

Tags: ios, swift, clock

Currently I'm writing an app that will need every iOS devices to have some sort of synchronized time in order to function correctly. I know I can use NSDate to get current time, but I'm not sure if all iOS devices (no matter what location setting it has, or maybe user sets the time manually) will have same NSDate. The synced time has to be accurate enough (< 10ms difference maximum). Can I just use NSDate directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot rely on NSDate to give you this information.

You can use a Real Time server to provide this information.
[Check](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-01-realtime-ios-apps-getting-started-with-swift-and-pubnub/), it may help you.

Check also about NTP protocol, you can easily use [this github project](https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp) to get from a trusted time server, the current time, whiteout rely on the device.

Comment: Someone told me iOS has one, and it's called mtp, which I couldn't find any information on. Do you know what is it?

Comment: Are you talking about NTP? its a protocol for time (apple has a server..), there are some implementations like this https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp in github, but basically, it ask for a trusted server, "what time is it?".

Comment: Edited the answer to put more info about it.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not sure if all iOS devices (no matter what location setting it has, or maybe user sets the time manually) will have same NSDate.

Obviously they won't, because some people *will* set the time manually, so it could be quite far off.

Comment: Someone told me iOS has one, and it's called mtp, which I couldn't find any information on. Do you know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Switch off "Automatically" -> set the time to whatever you wish. So clearly what you ask for cannot be possible.

If you want synchronisation, then the only way you can do this between multiple device is with a central server that keeps the time, and everyone uses the time reported by that server, in your code.

Comment: so iOS itself doesn't have a synchronized clock? Someone told me iOS has one, and it's called mtp, which I couldn't find any information on